# Irrational/Rational Zeroes of a Polynomial

Tags: calculus, functions

If a polynomial function has 3 real zeros and atleast one of them is a rational number, then must the other 2 be irrational? Why/why not?

Comment: ...isn't this trivial? If _only_ one is rational, then the other two are by definition irrational. Perhaps you have some slightly different version of this question in mind?

Comment: (For instance, 'if a polynomial with rational coefficients has exactly three zeros and one is rational, must the other two be linearly dependent over $\mathbb{Q}$?' is a plausible question close to yours)

Comment: Did you even try anything? The first thing that comes to mind is $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$

Answer (score 2):

Consider some examples:

- $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)$
- $(x-1)(x^2-2)$

Do these answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Counter example:  $(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6$ is a polynomial with 3 real roots: 1,2,3.